# How do I set podcast release date in iTunes using Applescript?

Tags: itunes, applescript

I would like to add the release date to podcasts that I've imported into iTunes, but my applescript is returning an error about the date object.

```
    tell application "iTunes"
    set theSelection to selection
    if theSelection is not {} and (length of theSelection) is 1 then
        set theTrack to item 1 of theSelection
        log release date of theTrack as text
        set release date of theTrack to date ("2011-12-23T08:00:00Z" as string)

        refresh theTrack
    end if
end tell
```

The line `set release date of theTrack to date ("2011-12-23T08:00:00Z" as string)` gives me this error

`error "Invalid date and time date 2011-12-23T08:00:00Z." number -30720`

How do I make the string **2011-12-23T08:00:00Z** into a date object that applescript won't complain about?

Comment: Ok the property is read-only, so I'll have to use something like Subler.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the "release date" tag within iTunes using Applescript because the property is **read-only**.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation may say that it's read-only (and it does say that), but I have observed that if I have a date value, it totally still works:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with theTrack in selection
        set theDate to date("11/1/2003")
        set release date of theTrack to theDate
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

The string-to-date conversion depends on your locale settings (section "Formats" of "Language & Text" Preference pane in Snow Leopard), and you can also examine the format by executing the output of AppleScript command `current date`.

However, there's a way of making date initialization in AppleScript locale-independent (and thus portable):

```
set d to current date -- initialize new date object
set {year of d, month of d, day of d, time of d} to {2011, 12, 23, 8 * hours + 13 * minutes + 39} -- the last number is seconds
-- d is now set to 2011/12/23 08:13:39
```

Comment: by the way: if you want to always supply the date as text in a specific format, you could use a parser such as this one: https://gist.github.com/1852783

Comment: thanks, but I won't be able to use applescript after all. Please see my answer.